# Meta-SO Community: Please stop down-voting legitimate questions

Tags: discussion, down-votes, meta, behavior

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Meta FAQ page should include more verbiage about downvotes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/meta-faq-page-should-include-more-verbiage-about-downvotes)
>   [Why do people take downvoting on meta so personally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20676/why-do-people-take-downvoting-on-meta-so-personally)
>   [Why are downvotes different on meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-downvotes-different-on-meta)

Downvoting on Meta Stack Overflow should mean one of two things:

- On feature requests/bugs, it means "I don't like your feature, I don't think it should be implemented"
- On discussions - your question is really badly formed, gibberish, or plain boring.

(Enlighten me if I have missed something)

Now, several times recently, people [have down-voted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45988/will-a-clone-force-stack-overflow-to-open-source) some ["discussion" questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46282/why-does-it-take-1000-rep-to-show-the-total-up-down-vote-counts-closed) that I asked, that I don't think were badly formed.

My theory is that these down-voters mentally mistook my question for a feature request, and down-voted to show their discontent at the feature request.

Am I correct in understanding that questions that are closed as duplicates should not be down-voted just for being duplicates (rather, it should be closed as such)?

Comment: Well, this was begging to be down-voted, I know, I know :)

Comment: Let's start with some dupes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20676/why-do-people-take-downvoting-on-meta-so-personally http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/meta-faq-page-should-include-more-verbiage-about-downvotes http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42558/why-are-downvotes-different-on-meta

Comment: downvotes on Meta tend to indicate disagreement in addition to the *bad question* and *i'm bored* meanings.  that meaning isn't limited to feature requests.

Comment: @random - actually, the first is not really a dupe, more a "consequence" of this question.

Comment: This question has all the hallmarks of "Don't downvote my questions, no matter what you may think of them." @gno

Comment: Downvotes in part look to discourage bad behaviour. Asking dupes would be considered bad behaviour.

Comment: well, if it makes you feel any better, I did change the front page filter threshold on meta from -4 to -10 .. so any given question can survive a lot of downvoting before being banished away from the front page.

Comment: @Jeff - That's a quite useful, but are you sure about the -10? this question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46308/users-should-not-be-able-to-edit-closed-questions-in-order-to-make-them-more-pala) currently has -8 and is not found on the front page anymore. (or maybe this change occurred after the last edit, I don't know)

Comment: Irony overflow.

Comment: Funny, I was about to write up something calling for *more* downvotes on questions.

Comment: @Jeff: since meta is a low-traffic site anyway (where posts can survive for a day on the front page), and downvoted questions are still useful discussion topics, perhaps it might be easier and simpler to simply remove the front page filter for meta entirely?

Comment: @random - see this question about dups and "bad behaviour" - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46420/is-asking-dups-considered-a-bad-behavior

Comment: Also, none of the supposed dups for this question are feature requests, so I don't understand how can this be considered a dup (well, except this one which is certainly not a dup to my feature request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/meta-faq-page-should-include-more-verbiage-about-downvotes)

Answer (score 16):

Besides the usual "voting is anonymous, and it's up to each individual to vote for whatever reason" yadayada, here are some typical reasons for downvoting on meta:

1. On feature requests: The voter disagrees and thinks this would not be a good feature.
2. On discussion questions: a) the question is a de-facto feature request – see 1.; b) the OP bases his question on assumptions that the downvoter disagrees with; c) the question is just a rant that's unhelpful or close to offensive
3. On bug reports: a: lack of freehand circles in screenshots; b) bug is not easily reproducible
4. On support questions: a) the question is a de-facto feature request – see 1.; b) it is an actual support question, but includes a "this stupid site doesn't work" outburst
5. On any question or answer: a) the voter wants to [call Commander Keen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/stack-overflows-voting-system-is-not-entertaining-enough/41397#41397); b) the post mentions Commander Keen

Here are the data dump-based probabilities that you end up with a negative score on your question, based on the tag:

```
                 total count  with score < 0  percentage
bug              1392         38              2,73%
support          1613         71              4,40%
discussion       3808         364             9,56%
feature-request  2789         356             12,76%
```

Comment: -1 for mentioning the C-Who-Shall-Not-Be-Named...

Comment: added 3b: bugs should be reproducible or we will downvote them mercilessly.